# regexp to match characters not flowed by a character that is repeated an amount of times

Tags: javascript, regex

i built this regexp to match letters and numbers and dots
dots only if they are not repeated successfully
example :

```
something.somethnElse.another.then.something
```

this is a match because the dots are separated.
but in the following case :

```
something..thensomething
```

is no match because there is one or more dots next to eachother
this is my regexp, recommend me please why it's not working

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+(?!\.{2,})
```

i tried also

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+(?![\.]+)
```

but they both give a match for successful dots

Comment: try `/^(\w+\.)*\w+$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. You can use this regex:

```
^(?!.*?\.{2})[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rQ8xB3/3)

**PS:** No need to escape the dot inside character class

Comment: it fails if there's at least 1 dot whiting the other words that is not followed successfully by a dot [RefEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rQ8xB3/2)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use beginning of string `^` and end of string `$` anchors and place the lookahead at the beginning.

```
/^(?!.*\.{2})[a-z0-9.]+$/i
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lL2hI0/1)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the expression should be anchored, otherwise it only requires a very minimal match.

Additionally, you could think of your expression as a chain of letters and digits that can be interrupted by exactly one dot.

So:

```
/^(?:[a-z0-9]+|\.(?!\.))*$/
```

Comment: but what do you mean please by the expression should be anchored ? the  start and end of expression anchors ? like the `^` and how would that give us less matches if not used ? thanks

Comment: and why the capturing group ? `(?:)`

Comment: @Amine That's not a capturing group ... it's a container for repeating the alternation :)